# Get attribute with selector value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<input type="text" value="Here" id="aaa"> <br />
<span id="check">check</span>

$('#check').click(function(){
   alert($('input [value="Here"]').attr('id'));
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mHYsJ/

why this not working? How can i get attribute with selector VALUE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not use space between the element and the attribute selector, currently your selector tries to find a element with attribute `value='here'` within the input element, try the following:

```
$('#check').click(function(){
   alert($('input[value="Here"]').attr('id'));
})
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mHYsJ/2/)

Comment: @MickAsgorther You are welcome, because `input[value="Here"]` has no parent with class of `test` try this: http://jsfiddle.net/mHYsJ/4/

Answer (score 2):

Remove the space should be:

```
alert($('input[value="Here"]').attr('id'));
```

Comment: Because you're looking for a parent element with the class test that has a child input element with the value equal to here... try this:  `alert($('input.test[value="Here"]').attr('id'));`

Answer (score 2):

Remove the space in your selector.

```
$('input[value="Here"]').attr('id')
```

The space means "descendant of".

Comment: @MickAsgorther: Like I said, the space means "descendant of".  You are looking for an input that is a child of `.test`.  You want `$('input.test[value="Here"]')`.

Comment: @MickAsgorther because JQuery isn't loading on fiddler.

Comment: @Wesley, uh? because *it's not loading on fiddler* he gets an object back for the above selector? I think you should revise your statement.

Comment: @MickAsgorther probably because you didn't add the `.attr('id')` afterwards.  `$('input.test[value="Here"]').attr('id')` like his answer says

Comment: @Gabe Sorry, I was trying to work with JQuery running a few tests in the console. Looks like Fiddler loads the page in a separate resource for execution.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a useful function (taken from [here](https://github.com/jmas/html_widgets/blob/master/widgets.js~)) that gets all elements containing value for specified attribute:

```
var getAllElementsWithAttribute = function (attribute) {
    var matchingElements = [];
    var allElements = document.getElementsByTagName('*');
    for (var i = 0; i < allElements.length; i++) {
        if (allElements[i].getAttribute(attribute)) {
            matchingElements.push(allElements[i]);
        }
    }
    return matchingElements;
};
```

Comment: Do not copy content from elsewhere without clear attribution. It is seen as plagiarism. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing